# How can I Scrapy to "re-parse" html pages recorded in a database?

Tags: python, postgresql, scrapy

I have recorded html page on my database with Scrapy. I would like to reparse them with the same pipeline. How can I fetch pages from the database so it follow the same pipeline as the normal Scrapy pipeline ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own [downloader middleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#writing-your-own-downloader-middleware) and mimic what standard `HttpCacheMiddleware` is doing. Details depend on how exactly you want to proceed and if you want to reuse current spider(s).

If you want to go with currect spiders, then your middleware would have to:

1. Get fingerprint of each request in `process_request` method.
2. Match this fingerprint with saved HTML page.
3. Return `Response` crafted from that HTML.

The advantage is that you don't have to touch your spider(s). The drawback is that the website might have changed in the meantime and current content doesn't have to match exactly the saved content.

If you wish to create new spider or modify currect, then:

1. Your spider should implement `start_requests` method and yield `Request`s that your middleware can handle (e.g. filenames, database IDs).
2. Based on the `Request`, middleware reads the saved page and returns `Response` crafted from the HTML.

The advantage is that you'll process exactly what you have saved. The drawback is that you would have to implement another spider for this purpose.